# Clean up excessive words in a date field

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have a text filed called "TempD" in an Access table MissingTF469Temp. This field will update the date by finding it from a long string after a specific word "Effective Date". But due to a recent change in the actual string it is taking an extra letter "I" at the end of the date in some instances. I'd like to have an sql code to remove this excessive character.

Any help please.

```
Tue, Mar 29, 2016
Wed, Mar 9, 2016I
Fri, Apr 22, 2016
Fri, Apr 1, 2016 
Mon, Apr 4, 2016 
Mon, Apr 25, 2016
Mon, Mar 21, 2016
Wed, May 11, 2016
Fri, Apr 1, 2016 
Mon, Apr 4, 2016 
Mon, Apr 4, 2016I
Mon, Apr 4, 2016I
Mon, Apr 4, 2016I
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 11, 2016
Fri, Mar 18, 2016
Fri, Mar 18, 2016
Mon, Mar 21, 2016
Mon, Mar 21, 2016
Mon, Mar 21, 2016
Mon, Mar 21, 2016
Mon, Mar 28, 2016
Fri, Apr 1, 2016 
Fri, Apr 1, 2016 
Fri, Mar 4, 2016I
Tue, Mar 8, 2016I
Tue, Mar 8, 2016I
```

Comment: below is the code I entered, but it doesn't seems like doing anything for me. any updates please             UPDATE MissingTF469temp SET tempD = LEFT(tempD, len(tempD)-1)
WHERE tempD LIKE '%I';

Comment: One of these should work: `WHERE tempD LIKE '*I'` ... or ... `WHERE tempD ALIKE '%I'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How did you end up in that situation? Please use date fields for dates, not characters, and insert them in [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, like 'YYYY-MM-DD'.

Human-readable formats like yours should be kept for presentation only.

For your question, this should do the trick:

```
UPDATE table
SET field_name = LEFT(field_name, len(field_name)-1)
WHERE field_name LIKE '*I';
```